# Can't edit driven number value, see graph editor for the driver setup

Tags: drivers

Good day. I get the error "Can't edit driven number value, see graph editor for the driver setup." I have a leg that I will bend. To make it look good, I decided to follow this video (https://youtu.be/CaHomz6gPWY?list=PLRNEtMVoxM681OU2OEl5FDH-6O8CLlP8X). But after I follow it step by step and install the driver, my value is reset to zero, the transformation is not applied, and this error also appears. If I uncheck "Does F-Curve contribute to result" in the drivers editor, then the transformation is applied, but the error keeps coming out and the shape keys do not work correctly. I created a new file from scratch, and used a regular cylinder, but the error appears anyway. Rotation of the model in Video happens to be set to X and in my model also rotation is set to X. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

So. I finally solved the problem by following this video  (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f3JWNIkwBZ8). To fix it, in the Driver window add  Modifier Generator and change Y in it from -1 to 1.
[image]