# I don't see graph in Graph Editor window

Tags: graph-editor

Good day. I'm looking at the video where author makes manipuations in Graph Editor window. I'm followin them exactly, but graph doesn't display in that window for me, only Driver Editor is displayed. Why?

video
[image]

my window

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are looking a video made on an older version of Blender which had the driver edition as a sub-part of the graph editor, whereas the current version has separated them into two distinct editors.

Comment: Thank you, maybe you know how to solve my other problem?
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/219281/cant-edit-driven-number-value-see-graph-editor-for-the-driver-setup